# NHibernate second level cache for subclass only

Tags: nhibernate, caching

I am using many classes per table mapping(subclasses with discriminator).
**Is there a way to turn on second level caching for specific subclass only ?**
NHibernate version is 3.1.0

If I put the tag `<cache usage="read-only"/>` right after the subclass tag, I get error at runtime(tells that cache is invalid child element for element subclass).

```
<class name="MyDomain.ParentClass, MyDomain" table="MyDomainClass">    
    <subclass name="MyDomain.SubClass, MyDomain"  discriminator-value="SubClass">    
    </subclass>    
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) (ch. 25.1) says:

> Add <cache usage="read-write|nonstrict-read-write|read-only"/> (just after <class>) in the mapping of the entities you want to cache. It also works for collections (bag, list, map, set, ...).

So, sadly, no subclass.